# Random boxes in a grid JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I created a grid with random boxes, yellow and one red.
The problem is that when I refresh the page sometimes the red box doesn't appear, is hidden somewhere, I guess under a yellow box. Also, sometimes even the yellow boxes are not all displayed.
I guess there's a problem in the loop to create them?

```js
var grid = document.getElementById("grid-box");

for (var i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
  var square = document.createElement("div");
  square.className = 'square';
  square.id = 'square' + i;
  grid.appendChild(square);
}

var obstacles = [];

while (obstacles.length < 10) {
  var randomIndex = parseInt(99 * Math.random());

  if (obstacles.indexOf(randomIndex) === -1) {
    obstacles.push(randomIndex);
    document.getElementById('square' + randomIndex).style.backgroundColor = 'yellow';

  }
}

var playerOne = [];

while (playerOne.length < 1) {
  var randomIndex = parseInt(99 * Math.random());

  if (playerOne.indexOf(randomIndex) === -1) {
    playerOne.push(randomIndex);
    document.getElementById('square' + randomIndex).style.backgroundColor = 'red';

  }
}
```

```css
#grid-box {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  font-size: 0;
  position: relative;
}

#grid-box>div.square {
  font-size: 1rem;
  vertical-align: top;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 10%;
  height: 10%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<div id="grid-box"></div>
```

Comment: `if (playerOne.indexOf(randomIndex) === -1)` seems to be the mistake as you only populated obstacles. You should use `if(playerOne.indexOf(randomIndex) === -1 obstacles.indexOf(randomIndex) === -1)` just to be sure it's not used

Answer (score 2):

You have to change 2 things:

**1. initial value of i should be 0 when you create squares**

**2. when you make red box then**

replace

```
if (playerOne.indexOf(randomIndex)
```

with

```
if (playerOne.indexOf(randomIndex) === -1 && obstacles.indexOf(randomIndex) === -1) {
```

### Here is the final code:

```
var grid = document.getElementById("grid-box");

// create 100 squares
for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) { // first change
 var square = document.createElement("div");
 square.className = 'square';
 square.id = 'square' + i;
 grid.appendChild(square);
}

var obstacles = [];

while (obstacles.length < 10) {
var randomIndex = parseInt(99 * Math.random());
if (obstacles.indexOf(randomIndex) === -1) {        
    obstacles.push(randomIndex);
    document.getElementById('square' + randomIndex).style.backgroundColor = 'yellow';
 }
}

var playerOne = [];
while (playerOne.length < 1) {
 var randomIndex = parseInt(99 * Math.random());    
 if (playerOne.indexOf(randomIndex) === -1 && obstacles.indexOf(randomIndex) === -1) { // second change
     playerOne.push(randomIndex);
     document.getElementById('square' + randomIndex).style.backgroundColor = 'red';
  }
}
```

It is because, when randomIndex would be zero(0), then you are searching element whose id is "square0" and it is not available because your for loop starts runs from 1 to 100.

Answer (score 1):

`Math.random()` would sometimes return `0`, but your ids are starting from `1` eg: 'square1', there is no 'square0' `div`.

Make your loop starts from `0`:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++){
  // Code here
}
```

Comment: An addition to this, playerOne is set just once, playerOne.length < 1, therefore no need for playerOne array. But setting it doesn't check obstacles. So it is easy to happen that player overrides obstacle